# How to datagrid cell tooltip size(Height/width)?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tooltip, wpfdatagrid

I have created a **WPF** application which includes a **DataGrid**. I can easily set a tooltip for the cells. What I would like to do is to be able to set the width and height of this tooltip manually. I have the following XAML:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MessageColumnTooltip"  
                               Binding="{Binding Message}" Header="Message" Width="*" >
              <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Message}" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip.Width" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip.Height" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
                 </Style>
              </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
           </DataGridTextColumn>
```

But the value set to *Tooltip.Width* and *Tooltip.Height* is applied to the cell size instead even though I set the Height and Width of of the cell as well. I have tried to **only** set *Tooltip.Width* and *Tooltip.Height* as well, but did not work. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MessageColumnTooltip" Binding="{Binding Message}" Header="Message" Width="*" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip Width="500" Height="500">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```